# How do I set a boundary in which my image can go through in Pygame?How do I keep an image from going behind another?

Tags: python, pygame

This is the code for my pygame

```
import pygame
import os

img_path=os.path.join('C:/Desktop/Python Stuff','Angry Birds.jpg')
class pic(object):
    def __init__(self):
    """ The constructor of the class """
    self.image = pygame.image.load(img_path)
    # the bird's position
    self.x = 0
    self.y = 0


def handle_keys(self):
    """ Handles Keys """
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    dist = 5
    if key[pygame.K_DOWN]: # down key
        self.y += dist # move down
    elif key[pygame.K_UP]: # up key
        self.y -= dist # move up
    if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]: # right key
        self.x += dist # move right
    elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]: # left key
        self.x -= dist # move left

def draw(self, surface):
    """ Draw on surface """
    # blit yourself at your current position
    surface.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))
```

This is the screen size. Is this where the I should restrict the image's boundaries?

```
pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode([1500,850])
Pic=pic()

pygame.display.set_caption('Angry Birds')
```

This is the image that I want to have a boundary for

```
pic=pygame.image.load('Angry Birds.jpg')

keep_going=True
while keep_going:
    event=pygame.event.poll()
   *emphasized text* if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
    pygame.quit()
    running = False
Pic.handle_keys()
screen.blit(pic, (-200, 0))
Pic.draw(screen)
```

This image is what the 'Angry Birds' image is going behind. How do I stop it from going behind this image?

```
tux=pygame.image.load('Rock Lee.gif')



screen.blit(tux,(500,600))
screen.blit(tux,(500,400))
screen.blit(tux,(500,0))
screen.blit(tux,(900,200))
screen.blit(tux,(900,400))
screen.blit(tux,(900,600))
screen.blit(tux,(1300,0))
screen.blit(tux,(1300,200))
screen.blit(tux,(1300,600))
pygame.display.get_surface([1500,850]).get_size([1500,850])
pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: When writing questions it's very important to make sure you get the code right. There's many indention errors so it's hard to see what your code does. It's also important to have classes starting with a capital letter and variable in all lowercase letters. Also, what do you mean by *'set boundaries'*? Do you mean make your image a certain size, create visual borders around your image or something else?

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Try to be more **specific**. What do you mean by _boundaries_?, and what is _I wish for the bird to not hit the image_ mean? Try to fix your **ambiguity** errors before asking your question.

Comment: Sorry for that. What I really wanted to know was this: a) I don't want my image(the one that moves) to go past the Pygame window. As of now, it is able to leave my sight, and I want to know how to stop that. b) THe image that is moving(Angry Birds) is able to move around be hind the other image(Rock Lee). I would also like to know how to stop that.

Answer (score 1):

## A) Keep rect on screen

The simplest way would be using [`Rect.clamp_ip(rect)`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.clamp_ip) on a [`Sprite`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite)

```
screen_size = Rect(1500,850)

# right after when you move the bird
bird.rect.clamp_ip(screen_size)
```

## B) rect on rect collision

```
# Where .xvel and .yvel are bird's movement per frame
new_rect = bird.rect.move(bird.vxel, bird.yvel)
if not new_rect.collide_rect(other_bird.rect)
    bird.rect = new_rect
else
    print("Ouch!")
```

Answer (score 0):

### Border collision

An easy way to implement border collision is to just check if the current position is outside the screen, and if it is you move it back. It's easiest done by creating a Rect object from the *screen* which you could pass in an **update** method of your class *pic* (classes should start with capital letter). So start with creating an update method were you pass the *screen* object.

Also, since the x and y position reference the **top left** of the image you need to take that in consideration when checking for border collision with the right side and the bottom. Best would be to create attributes *width* and *height* instead of what I'm doing below.

```
def update(self, screen):
    """Method that check border collision for object 'pic'."""
    border = screen.get_rect()
    width = self.image.get_width()
    height = self.image.get_height()

    if self.x < border.left:
        # You collided with the left side of the border.
        # Move your character back to the screen
        self.x = border.left

    elif self.x > border.right - width:
        # You collided with the right side of the border.
        # Move your character back to the screen
        self.x = border.right - width

    if self.y < border.top:
        # You collided with the top of the border.
        # Move your character back to the screen
        self.y = border.top

    elif self.y > border.bottom - height:
        # You collided with the bottom of the border.
        # Move your character back to the screen
        self.y = border.bottom - height
```

All you have to do is call this method every time in your loop, like so:

```
Pic.handle_keys()  # Variables should be all lowercase! Not like it's currently.
Pic.update(screen)  # Variables should be all lowercase! Not like it's currently.
Pic.draw(screen)  # Variables should be all lowercase! Not like it's currently.
```

---

### Keep image in front

When blitting to the screen it draws each image on top of each other. In your case you're blitting your character and then the rocks, meaning the rocks always be on top of your character. Changing this is simple, blit the rocks first and the character last and your character will end up in front of your rocks.